# Is there a way to change the color of a combo box Button for the drop down list in Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access, combobox

I am wondering if there is a way to actually change the button color on the combo box from the standard grey?? I tried changing windows themes and looked through the properties but all I can find are properties to change the background and fore color, but not the actual drop down button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably try with windows-apis, but that would be quite complicated and access doesn't handle everything like other windows apps - so you may run into more problems than expected.

An easier way is, to create a button with the same measurements than the dropdown-button, and position it over the dropdown button.

In the on-click event procedure you set `myCombo.dropdown`.

Perhaps you also want to set tabstop of the combobox to false so the user doesn't have two stops for that combobox if he choses to go through the form with the tabkey.

Its not a perfect solution regarding UI but its close.